# After MikTex update the en-dash ligature doesn't work in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, miktex, ligatures

Recently, after more than a year, I update my MikTex packages. After that, I notice that XeLaTeX makes PDF differently, in the sense that en-dash and em-dash ligatures don't work properly if they starts after a letter (they work after the space). I install TexLive 2023, but on my computer it also has the same problem. However, Overleaf's TexLive works fine. Any idea what kind of a collision I have on my computer? Unfortunately, I use Windows 10, so many linux solutions don't work for me. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[Script=Cyrillic]{serbian}
\newfontfamily{\serbianfont}[Mapping=ascii-to-serbian, Script=Cyrillic, Language=Serbian, Ligatures=TeX]{Noto Serif}
\begin{document}
dash - en dash -- em dash --- works

dash-en dash--em dash---doesn't work
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can confirm that this issue also arises on an up-to-date MacTeX/TeXLive distribution.